# How can I recursively FTP a directory structure using Jsch?

Tags: java, ftp, jsch

I'm trying to traverse a directory and upload all contents and directories in the same structure.

**This is an example structure:**

```
Dir1/
....Dir1_1/
....Dir1_2/
........Dir1_2_1/
............file.txt
Dir2/
....file.txt
....file2.txt
Dir3/
Dir4/
index.html
index.css
example.file
```

**I've tried the following:**

```
private void ftpFiles(File[] files, ChannelSftp channelSftp) throws SftpException, FileNotFoundException {
    for (File file : files) {
        System.out.println("Uploading: " + file.getName());

        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println(file.getName() + " is a directory");
            SftpATTRS attrs;
            try {
                channelSftp.stat(file.getName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(file.getName() + " does not exist. Creating it...");
                channelSftp.mkdir(file.getName());
            } 
            channelSftp.cd(file.getName());

            this.ftpFiles(file.listFiles(), channelSftp);
        } else {
            channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(file), file.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm taking an array of top level files, and recursively going down each one.

> The problem is once I hit the first directory and `cd` into it, all further files and directories are inside of this.

*Example:* `/Dir1/Dir1_1/Dir1_2/Dir1_2_1/Dir2/Dir3/Dir4/...etc`

How can I do a `../` with my channel while calling this recursively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like (pseudo code):

```
List<Files> directories = new ArrayList<> ();
if (file is directory) directories.add(file);
else dowloadFile();

for (File f : directories) {
  cd(f);
  ftpFiles(listFiles());
  cd(..);
}
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you sir. Also so much more concise than the linked question's answers